# T-SQL Trigram and Fuzzy Searching Algorithms for multiple phrases

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, algorithm

Although I've found multiple posts here and articles on web, nothing quite solves an issue I have and am looking for guidance.

Environment:  VB.NET 2010 w/SQL Server 2008 R2

My Problem.
I have a table that contains 4 columns, each with a unique "Phrase".  Multiple rows

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
Phrase1 Phrase2 Phrase3 Phrase4
Phrase1 Phrase2 Phrase3 Phrase4
Phrase1 Phrase2 Phrase3 Phrase4
etc.
```

In application, user is either presented a phrase or can type in their own phrase.  The need is for them to take this phrase, search the database table and be presented with the row that contains the closest matches.

I cannot use CLR in SQL and We do not have MDS (mentioned in multiple articles) loaded.  In addition, we do not have Full-Text turned on (but "might" be allowed to do so).

My Tests:
An example might be the phrase "Playing Basketball".
The database might hold "Playing basketball with son" or "Playing basketball with team" or "Basketball Team" , etc.

I have tried looking at a Levenshtein calculation, but it didn't score the above the best...it found "Playing racquetball" as lowest score.

Currently I'm brute forcing by splitting the entered phrase into words and doing a "like" and presenting the "matches".

I'd like to find a way to make this more accurate (and possibly weighted).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How big is the database? I am just wondering if its easier to pull into some arrays and let vb do the complicated part. Otherwise probably need some dynamic SQL

Comment: Not large.  like ...1000 rows or so of data.  VB=complicated part, maybe, but that is what i was looking for ...methodology etc.   Dynamic SQL...uh no.